# How to configure Editor js in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, editorjs

I am currently making a blogging site in python and django and for blog editing a saw many text editing plugins for django like ckeditor but the one. I liked is Editor.js

Can anyone tell me how to can I put the editor.js in Django the safest method possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the plugin to use Editor.js in the django admin area.
[django-editorjs](https://pypi.org/project/django-editorjs/)